# nginx proxypass squid

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, squid, proxypass

I'm trying to run squid server behind nginx.
my sample configuration :

```
location ~* ^/get/(.*) 
{   
    proxy_pass http://ip:3128;
    proxy_set_header Host evenstatichostnamefortest.com;
    proxy_set_header  Request-URI http://evenstatichostnamefortest.com/samplefile.zip;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

output :

```
http://server.com/get/www.google.com
```

**squid Error:**

> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   /get/www.google.com
>
> **Invalid URL**

all I want is passing requests based on folders ( e.g mysite/get/videourl to youtube/videourl and mysite/dl/filename to my download service )
but I wonder why I can't even overide Request-URI and Host with statics values

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How's your `squid.conf` look? Is it set as a transparent proxy?

Comment: you mean  http_port 3128 transparent ?
squid works fine with browsers, but not with nginx

Comment: @NathanC : any suggestion ?

Comment: Did this ever work? stuck in the same situation